# Change camera output in Mac OS 10.6

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there any way to programatically change what the camera in Mac OS X outputs? Maybe apply a filter, so that all applications using the camera will see the camera image plus the applied filter?

If not programatically, or if not by using Objective-C, is there any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: So the filter needs to not only apply for the application running the filter, but it needs to apply the filter to all the displayed video ouput currently running?

Comment: Yes. All the applications that receive the stream from the camera, would receive the altered stream. Something that would stand between the original stream and the application receiving it. Or something that alters the original stream...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create a custom driver of sorts, as many applications access the camera directly or with a low-level API, so forcing them to use your filtered stream would be hard to do.

Comment: Having a separate driver will not apply a filter on the original camera though, would it? But even so, this would be the next best thing... Do you know where I could find some documentation about it?

Comment: Agree with Blender, this isn't really feasible. If it was only for your application I'd say use Quartz, but it looks like that isn't the case.

On a side note, Blender, are you actually involved in the Blender project? If so, kudos!

Comment: I've never made a single driver in my life, especially for Mac, so I can't help you there. Apple seems to have a framework for developing drivers, though, so you are in luck: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_Kit